# Finding the number of letter & number combinations of strings?

Tags: permutation

I am trying to find out how to come up with a x character string that can be made up of either numbers or letters to test a theory.

For example in a one character string, there are 36 possibilities:
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

This is easy to figure out, but how to I find out how many possibilities there are for a string that is x characters in length?

Comment: I was a bit hasty to answer; questions like this are probably better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, I thought it belonged in a more mathy section. Didn't know there was a stackexchange for math. :)

Comment: Typical Mathematics question ! Must be moved from SO to math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just A<sup>N</sup>, where A is the number of characters in your alphabet (i.e. 36) and N is the number of characters in your output string.

If you can't use a character more than once, then it is `A! / (A-N)!` where `!` is the factorial operator.

Comment: How does one figure out, that it is just A^N ? How does one get there? or what to study to understand it ? thanks btw for the formula